# Fathers computer

Tags: password-recovery

My father passed away in a traffic accident and I’ve been trying to access his laptop but with Ubuntu installed Im not real good with computers but can navigate them ok his passwords for Ubuntu how do I find or get

Comment: You've not provided any product/release details; but I'd usually boot a *live* OS that I mostly knew how to operate, then `mount` the internal drive of the device & explore... If encryption is detected, it'll be much harder, but you've provided no specifics. You maybe able to change the password directly from the *live* media (*just as you would a windows device too*!) but again you may not. The *live* media is an OS on thumb-drive, so you're using the machine's internal drive as a secondary disk & by-passing *most* security on that drive..  (*this isn't Ubuntu specific*)

Comment: Somewhat the program has turned WiFi off until I can log into the keyring